# What is the cause of Invalid use of null error 94 in a MouseMove event handler in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mousemove event handler attached to a 3-column listbox called lstUneditedStudents in an Excel UserForm. The bound column is number 1. The column contains alphanumeric strings like this "A202H". Why am I getting an Invalid use of Null in this code? (ErrorLog is my own class which logs errors to a worksheet. That's working smoothly, documenting my errors as I debug.)

```
Private Sub lstUneditedStudents_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Button = 1 Then
        Dim dob As DataObject, listValue As String
        listValue = lstUneditedStudents.value
        If listValue <> "" Then
            Set dob = New DataObject
            dob.SetText listValue
            dob.StartDrag
        End If
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim errLog As New ErrorLog
        errLog.Log "frmEditClasses", "lstUneditedStudents_MouseMove", Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

When you click on the listbox, there is an annoying delay and then the listbox goes blank before re-populating. Once you let this settle down, the drag works and other subroutines handle the move from this listbox to another listbox. However, this error is still raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to check if lstUneditedStudents.value is null before assigning it to a variable. For example:

```
Private Sub lstUneditedStudents_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Button = 1 Then
        Dim dob As DataObject, listValue As String
        If Not IsNull(lstUneditedStudents.value) Then
            listValue = lstUneditedStudents.value
            If listValue <> "" Then
                Set dob = New DataObject
                dob.SetText listValue
                dob.StartDrag
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim errLog As New ErrorLog
        errLog.Log "frmEditClasses", "lstUneditedStudents_MouseMove", Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This line `If Not lstUneditedStudents.value Is Nothing Then` didn't do the trick, but I changed it to `If Not IsNull(lstUneditedStudents.value)` and got rid of the error.